# Sending data from View to Action

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

How do I send some data from the view back to the controller?

This is the select from where I get the data (sel1):

```
 <div class="form-group" style="margin: 0 auto;">
            <label for="sel1">Select a cat breed:</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <option>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BreedName)
                    </option>
                }
            </select>
        </div>
```

This is the script I tried to use to send data back:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    loadJasonData();
    $("#sel1").change(function () {
        loadJasonData();
    });
});

function loadJasonData() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "CatDetails",
        //url: "/CatCompare/CatDetails", i also tried this of url
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
         data: { name: $("#sel1").val() }
    })
}
```

And finally the controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CatDetails(string name)
    {
        var breedName = db.Breeds.FirstOrDefault(b => b.BreedName == name);

        ViewBag.name = breedName.BreedName;
        ViewBag.lifeSpan = breedName.Lifespan;
        ViewBag.height = breedName.Height;
        ViewBag.weight = breedName.Weight;
        ViewBag.shortDescription = breedName.ShortDescription;
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Test it by just sending the value "tigger" and putting a breakpoint in the Action, see if it is hit. Also check the Output window in Visual Studio, and the browser's console for errors. Also remove the first call to loadJasonData, I am doubtful that its call is intended.

Comment: I would also remove HttpGet if you intend to post data.

Comment: All i had t do was to remove [HttpGet]. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have to add **option value** to your select:

```
 <div class="form-group" style="margin: 0 auto;">
            <label for="sel1">Select a cat breed:</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <option value='@item.BreedName'>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BreedName)
                    </option>
                }
            </select>
        </div>
```

Then change your `loadJasonData()` method to this

```
function loadJasonData() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",           
        url: "/CatCompare/CatDetails",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
         data: { name: $("#sel1 option:selected").val() }
    })
}
```

at the last  remove  `[HttpGet]` in your action

```
  [HttpPost]

  public ActionResult CatDetails(string name)
    {
        var breedName = db.Breeds.FirstOrDefault(b => b.BreedName == name);

        ViewBag.name = breedName.BreedName;
        ViewBag.lifeSpan = breedName.Lifespan;
        ViewBag.height = breedName.Height;
        ViewBag.weight = breedName.Weight;
        ViewBag.shortDescription = breedName.ShortDescription;
        return View();
    }
```

**Note:**  Your action returns **a view**. If you want to return **json result** you have to use `return Json(yourData);`

Comment: Thank you Fatikhan!

It works, the "name" parameter in the Action is now populated with the breed name.

After a bit of testing, it seems it works only when i remove [HttpGet]. The <select> works with <option value='@item.BreedName'> the same as without the "value", as in my original code.

Why can't a Action accept [HttpPost] AND [HttpGet] ?
Why do you think <option value='@item.BreedName'> is better ?

Comment: I believe the value is taken from the text of the option, if a value attribute is not present. I cannot recall if this is a feature of jQuery or HTML.